# How can i pass multiple variables to my template in django?

Tags: python, django, django-views

Hey guys my files are organized as follows.

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^contact/', views.eurusd, name='eur'),
    url(r'^contact/', views.VaR, name='lol'),


]
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

from yahoo_finance import Currency

def eurusd (request):
    eur_usd = Currency('EURUSD')
    eur = ('EUR/USD Bid/Ask Price:    ' +eur_usd.get_bid() +' /   '+eur_usd.get_ask())
    return render(request, 'personal/basic.html', {'eur': eur})

def VaR (request):
    hallo = "this is a python sting"
    return render(request, 'personal/basic.html', {'lol': hallo})
```

basic.html

```
{% extends "personal/header.html" %}

{% block content %}
<p>{{eur}}</p>
<p>{{lol}}</p>
{% endblock %}
```

My question now is:
why is only the string from eur dictionary being returned in my template named basic.html and not the lol?
how can i pass multiple variables to my basic.html?

Answer (score 2):

You doesn`t need two functions, becouse you want to render template with two variables, so easiest way to do this - is write one functions that return in context two wariables. Some like this:

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^contact/', views.eurusd, name='eur'),
]
```

views.py

```
eur_usd = Currency('EURUSD')
    eur = ('EUR/USD Bid/Ask Price:    ' +eur_usd.get_bid() +' /   '+eur_usd.get_ask())
hallo = 'This is the python string'
    return render(request, 'personal/basic.html', {'eur': eur, 'hallo' : hallo})
```

With this code your tamplate will work fine

In your case django when try to find url, find first url that looks like your url, and then they do request to first function only.

Answer (score 1):

you just need one url pattern and with one function in your view, change your code to:

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^contact/', views.eurusd, name='eur'),
]
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

from yahoo_finance import Currency

def eurusd(request):
    eur_usd = Currency('EURUSD')
    eur = ('EUR/USD Bid/Ask Price:    ' +eur_usd.get_bid() +' /   '+eur_usd.get_ask())
    hallo = "this is a python sting"
    return render(request, 'personal/basic.html', {'eur': eur,'lol': hallo})
```